# Using CoreML Word Tagger on iOS 12.4

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, coremltools, createml

I trained a Core ML Text Classifier with Transfer Learning and Dynamic Embedding. It works great, but when I tried testing on a device running iOS 12.4, it failed to predict and gave me the error:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Prediction failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Prediction failed}
```

I also get this error when running on a simulator. I made sure the model could only be used on devices running iOS 12+. Is this model not supported on iOS 13? I saw these new features were released at this WWDC, but I was hoping/assuming they were backward compatible. Was I mistaken? If this model can't be run on iOS 12 devices, is there any way to export the model so it can be. Lastly, is there anywhere I can find a list of what models are supported on each iOS.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

New features that were introduced with Core ML 3 don't run on older devices, only on iOS 13 and up.

However, if your model has such features, I would have expected an error message when loading the model. Does the debug output pane show any other messages?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have a check for if available (iOS 12) and that silenced all the warnings. There were no other errors or warnings besides this. I created the model with the Create ML app and added it to my project. Works great on iOS 13. Do you know if there is a list of which Text Classifiers are available on iOS 12 vs 13. I couldn’t find it anywhere.

Comment: Yes, there is such a list in my book (link in profile). ;-) TextClassifier and WordTagger are supported since Core ML 2 (iOS 12) but Gazetteer and WordEmbedding are new in Core ML 3 (iOS 13). I don't think there are any other text models (although you can also do text stuff in a neural network, of course).

Comment: Awesome. I’ll check out the book. If TextClassifier is supported in iOS 12 why would I be having this issue? Is it because I’m using Dynamic Embedding?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer from a [WWDC 2019 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/428/) at the 10 minute mark. Transfer learning for text classification is new with iOS 13 and in order to save space, a pre-trained model is deployed on iOS 13 devices. When you train a model with transfer learning, this model modifies the pre-trained model on device. This is why using a TextClassifier with transfer learning doesn’t work on iOS 12